Why was charged less than I was supposed to?
A Chinese company in Hong Kong called JLCPCB says I was charged a grand total of $146.64 USD. The Bank Of Canada says on 2024-03-15 (which is the date the payment was made) $146.64 USD was worth 198.45 CAD. My bank says I was charged 205.56 CAD.
205.56 - 198.45 = 7.11. My tax rate is 5%. But 5% of 205.56 is 10.278.
That's a difference of 3.1$.
Why?
Did someone use an older exchange rate? CAD and USD are very stable, so even if someone used an exchange rate that was a couple weeks old, it should only make a difference of a few cents, not $3, right?
What else could have caused this? Tax incentives? I live in Alberta Canada.
When I enter this into my sales tracker, should I say the tax was $10.28 (5%)? JLCPCB cannot tell me how much tax I paid. They said they have nothing to do with it.
Of course 3$ is insignificant, but this can add up over time.
I am working on selling things online, so I will need to file income tax, which means this has to be accurate. Also, when do I need to file income tax? Is it only when I make over a certain amount of profit? Links to official sources explaining this would be very helpful.

You probably didn't pay any Canadian taxes yet. A Chinese company in Hong Kong isn't likely to be collecting Canadian taxes. What tax do you expect to have paid that is set at 5%? The extra charged in conversion from USD to CAD was most likely a foreign exchange fee charged by your credit card. Most cards charge an extra amount on top of the current exchange rate. It can be 2.5%, give or take.

The 5% is the tax I have to pay for the province I live in

What is the name of the tax? GST? If the seller isn't in Canada, you're probably not paying any such tax at all.

I'm new to the realm of finance, but it seems I didn't pay taxes on it? And yes, the tax is GST.

You should speak to an accountant if you're going into business.

@Chris W. Rea I can't speak to the Canadian experience, but I've bought online from Chinese merchants (using AliExpress, etc) for delivery to my home in Australia.  Several years ago, the Chinese merchants started adding 10% to the purchase price, specifically to cover the 10% Australian Goods and Services Tax.  I think that it's entirely possible that Canada has also started to force overseas merchants to remit GST to the Canadian authorities.
